# Retrieve answers from a checkbox grid of a Google Form with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to store the data of a Google Form into a Google Sheet. In the Google Form there's a checkbox grid that contains a list of questions. I want to get the values (the answers) of the checkbox grid, but since it's an array, the response I get is "[Ljava.lang.Object;@xxxxx". I'd like to know how to get each answer of that array (in this case, I need the option of the column that the user selected).

Here's the code I have:

```
function storeInSheets(e) {

  //Connects the Form with the Sheet
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetId");
  const hoja = sheet.getSheetByName("sheetName");

  //Answers
  const respuestaEnviada = e.response;
  const respuestas = respuestaEnviada.getItemResponses();

  let id = sheet.getSheetByName("sheetName").getLastRow();
  const date = (new Date());
  const focus = respuestas[0].getResponse();
  const area = respuestas[1].getResponse();
  const cod = respuestas[2].getResponse();
  const name = respuestas[3].getResponse();
  const montacarga = respuestas[4].getResponse();
  const horometro = respuestas[5].getResponse();
  const p1 = respuestas[6].getResponse();

  const array = [id, date, focus, area, cod, name, montacarga, horometro, p1];

  //Save answers in Google Sheet
  hoja.appendRow(array);
}

function permissions() {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetId");
  FormApp.getActiveForm();
}
```

**I also have a Trigger, that sends the answers to a Google Sheet when the Form is submitted.**

Comment: Do you know that Google Forms can send form responses directly to an spreadsheet? Why are you not using this built-in function?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware! :) I need to store that data into an existing spreadsheet. That spreadsheet has data from another script, but I need all of that together in one sheet.

Comment: Reading the responses from the form is very slow, if that becomes an issue  consider to read the responses from the spreadsheet or frome form submit event object for spreadsheet or use the new Forms API.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including `yourVariable`  as an element of `array` use `JSON.stringify(yourVariable)`.

---

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item

> For [CheckboxGridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-grid-item) questions, this returns a `String[][]` array in which the answers at row index `n` corresponds to the question at row `n + 1` in the checkbox grid. If a respondent did not answer a question in the grid, that answer is returned as `''`.